# Is there an ISubscriber event for completing a Pull Request in TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs

I am working on a plugin for TFS to hook certain operations.  I'm able to successfully hook code pushes via using an ISubscriber on PushNotification, but am having trouble finding any type that matches up with the completion of a Pull Request.

A little more on what I'm trying to do.  I currently have a PushNotification hook that has some branch specific checks that it does.  Some reject a push, others provide notifications to users using some complex rules.  I need a way to be able to provide the notifications at a minimum, and ideally prevent the pull request from going through.  I can't provide notifications prior to the pull request going through as the notifications should only occur for code being placed in our main repository.

Long term, I want to switch it over to using the webhooks and some async approval, but I don't have the time to adapt the tools to work like that and setup the additional server needed to make that happen.  If there's no good solution, I'll simply disable pull requests for now until I can write proper services for it, but if there is a way to reuse the adapted hooks that can run on the PushNotification ISubscriber, it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Do you want to complete pull request programmatically?

Comment: No, I don't need to complete it programatically, though, that might be a viable work around if I can disable making them go through without being programmatic.The main problem is trying to make sure I run checks at the point that code hits the protected repo, not before.